# Binding a dictionary to wpf toolkit chart

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have to following dictionary on my view model class

```
public class SpendingCategoriesViewModel
{
  public Dictionary<string, decimal> SpendingCategories = new Dictionary<string,decimal>
  {

        {"Petrol", 120.5m},

        {"Rent", 400},

        {"Food", 200}
  };
}
```

and the following XAML code

```
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="chartExpenses" Title="Expenses by Category" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
            <chartingToolkit:PieSeries Title="Category" ItemsSource="{Binding SpendingCategories}" IndependentValuePath="Key" DependentValuePath="Value">
            </chartingToolkit:PieSeries>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

The isn't displaying any data.
If I set the ItemsSource for the series manually in the views class it does show the data so I'm assuming there is something wrong with **ItemsSource="{Binding SpendingCategories}"** but I can't seem to see it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Binding `SpendingCategories` has to be a public Property.

```
public Dictionary<string, decimal> SpendingCategories { get; private set; }

public SpendingCategoriesViewModel()
{
    SpendingCategories = new Dictionary<string,decimal>
    {   
        {"Petrol", 120.5m},
        {"Rent", 400},
        {"Food", 200}
    };
}
```